# Wordpress and ACF - How to echo an element if ACF value is set

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php 
if ($a > $b):
    echo <li>Released: <?php the_field('date_released'); ?></li>
    echo <li>title: <?php the_field('title'); ?></li>
    echo <li>age: <?php the_field('age'); ?></li>
else if ($a == $b): 
    echo "Nothing";
endif;
```

This is the PHP code I have in WP. How can I echo the `<li>` element only if the ACF field has a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()`. `get_field` **returns** the value, `the_field()` **echoes** the data, so you want to use `get_field()` to check if the data exists first.

In this example I'm setting the field to a variable and then using an [ternary operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-ternary-operator/) to check if there is a value, echo that, if not, echo nothing.

###### EDIT

this removes the `$a` and `$b` variables:

```
<?php
$data_released = get_field( 'date_released' );
$title         = get_field( 'title' );
$age           = get_field( 'age' );

// if the variable has a value, echo the <li>, if not, echo nothing.
echo $data_released ? '<li>Released:' . $data_released . '</li>' : '';
echo $title ? '<li>Title:' . $title . '</li>' : '';
echo $age ? '<li>Age:' . $age . '</li>' : '';
```

```
<?php
$data_released = get_field( 'date_released' );
$title         = get_field( 'title' );
$age           = get_field( 'age' );

if ( $a > $b ) :
    // if the variable has a value, echo the <li>, if not, echo nothing.
    echo $data_released ? '<li>Released:' . $data_released . '</li>' : '';
    echo $title ? '<li>Title:' . $title . '</li>' : '';
    echo $age ? '<li>Age:' . $age . '</li>' : '';
elseif ( $a === $b ):
    echo 'Nothing';
endif;
```

###### A more verbose answer

This does the same thing, but uses explicit `if` statements.

```
<?php
$data_released = get_field( 'date_released' );
$title         = get_field( 'title' );
$age           = get_field( 'age' );

if ( $a > $b ) :
    // If the variable does not equal an empty string
    if ( $data_released !== '' ) :
        echo '<li>Released:' . $data_released . '</li>';
    endif;
    if ( $title !== '' ) :
        echo '<li>Title:' . $title . '</li>';
    endif;
    if ( $age !== '' ) :
        echo '<li>Age:' . $age . '</li>';
    endif;
elseif ( $a === $b ):
    echo 'Nothing';
endif;
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answers, im getting the error of Warning: Undefined variable $a in line 26, this line " if ( $a > $b ) : "

Comment: im getting error on variable

Comment: Those are your variables from **your** code. I assumed you have them defined somewhere else - since you asked about ACF. If not, we need to see more of your code. I wouldn't know what `$a` or `$b` are referenced to.

Comment: it was a rundom. sorry. im not good with that i copy that from the internet. maybe can you remove those variable on the code so that i will work properly. im not sure about this variables.

Comment: If I remove those, the code still may not work as expected, but you can give it a try

Comment: what do i change?

Comment: Thank you your a legends!! its work well now